# Unable to filter hbase records

Tags: java, hbase

I have a `Hbase` "User" table. Now I have the row keys of User table but I want to get only those user whose `dateOfBirth` is grater then a "Valid Date" and belongs to the key List.

Currently I am using

```
  Result[] result = table.get(keys);
```

for getting all users whose keys I have.

I am new in `Hbase`. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter;

FilterList fl = new FilterList();
Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("columnFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("column"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER, Bytes.toBytes(dateOfBirth));
fl.add(filter);
scan.setFilter(fl);

ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(scan);
```

You can get more info about filters in http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.filter.html